# Arquillian and @BeforeClass, @AfterClass annotations

Tags: testing, annotations, jboss-arquillian

It looks like mentioned annotations are executed inside the deployment. I need them to be run outside, let's say to start some simulator class on startup and stop it on the end. How can I do it? The simulator uses socket communication and it should not be started inside the server.

How to mix arquillian with "plain" junit(not executed in container).

Comment: Just to clarify what I want to reach. I have ear deployment, enhanced with some test, the test executes some functionality inside the ear. But I need to start some simulator which will be contacted by the ear deployment. Usually for this @BeforeClass would work, but here it is executed inside the ear, which forces me to package the simulator classes inside the ear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the arquillian @RunAsClient annotation combined with the junit @BeforeClass and @AfterClass:

```
@BeforeClass 
@RunAsClient // runs as client
public static void shouldBeAbleToRunOnClientSideBeforeRemoteTest() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("before!!");
}

@AfterClass 
@RunAsClient // runs as client
public static void shouldBeAbleToRunOnClientSideAfterRemoteTest() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("after!!");
}
```

Comment: I'm reusing some server code in my simulator. There is some static class I need to override with PowerMock, but using @Rule PowerMockRule, is not helping very much as the test expects the classes to be on server. I need to change the static class only "in client" is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 1):

The answer that Franck gives will certainly work, and will probably be what most users will want to use. If, however, you need to get some more detail about what's going on, or need some more control you can certainly hook into the Arquillian life cycle and register observers for all sorts of [events](http://docs.jboss.org/arquillian/spi/latest/org/jboss/arquillian/core/spi/event/Event.html) that Arquillian emits. Unfortunately, it isn't as easy as listening to a CDI event.

You'll need to create a services entry in META-INF/services with the file name of `org.jboss.arquillian.core.spi.LoadableExtension`. The contents of that file will be the Fully Qualified Name (FQN) of the classes that implement the `LoadableExtension` interface from Arquillian. You can then in the `register(ExtensionBuilder)` method register any classes that will observe events. Those classes will simply need a `public void methodName(@Observes EventType)` method for all the events they want to listen for. The `@Observes` annotation is in the `org.jboss.arquillian.core.api.annotation` package.

You can see this in action the Arquillian Recorder Reporter extension [here](https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-recorder/blob/master/arquillian-recorder-reporter/arquillian-recorder-reporter-impl/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/org.jboss.arquillian.core.spi.LoadableExtension), [here](https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-recorder/blob/master/arquillian-recorder-reporter/arquillian-recorder-reporter-impl/src/main/java/org/arquillian/recorder/reporter/ReporterExtension.java), and [here](https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-recorder/blob/master/arquillian-recorder-reporter/arquillian-recorder-reporter-impl/src/main/java/org/arquillian/recorder/reporter/impl/ReporterLifecycleObserver.java). I understand this is probably more than what most people will want to do, but again, if you need the power and hooks, Arquillian should be able to give you what you need.